# Non-blocking realtime redirection stdout from process to wx.TextCtrl control

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I've got the countdown.exe file (source code of this file is below). When this files is executed he write in console every second text. I start execution of this file when my GUI python app is executed:

```
self.countdown_process = subprocess.Popen("countdown.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I redirect stdout in subprocess.PIPE and start thread `out_thread` which read stdout of this process and add to TextCtrl:

```
out_thread = OutTextThread(self.countdown_process.stdout, self.AddText)
out_thread.start()
```

This is the full code of my python app:

```
import os
import sys
import wx

import subprocess, threading

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None)
        self._init_ctrls()

    def _init_ctrls(self):
        self.OutText = wx.TextCtrl(id=wx.NewId(), value='', name='OutText',
                                   parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 0),
                                   size=wx.Size(0, 0), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH2)

        self.OutText.AppendText("Starting process...\n")
        self.OutText.AppendText("Waiting 10 seconds...\n")
        self.countdown_process = subprocess.Popen("countdown.exe", shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out_thread = OutTextThread(self.countdown_process.stdout, self.AddText)
        out_thread.start()

    def AddText(self, text):
        self.OutText.AppendText(text)

class OutTextThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, std_out, cb):
        super(OutTextThread, self).__init__()
        self.std_out = std_out
        self.cb = cb

    def run(self):
        text = None
        while text != '':
            text = self.std_out.readline()
            self.cb(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

The C++ code of countdown.exe is simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void wait ( int seconds )
{
  clock_t endwait;
  endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
  while (clock() < endwait) {}
}

int main ()
{
  int n;
  printf ("Starting countdown...\n");
  for (n=10; n>0; n--)
  {
    printf ("%d\n",n);
    wait (1);
  }
  printf ("FIRE!!!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

But i have some problem. I start my python app and i must wait 10 second and only 10 seconds the stdout of countdown.exe is written in TextCtrl as you can see on picture below:
[image]
I want the realtime writing the stdout of countdown.exe in TextCtrl (self.OutText). How I can do this?
I tried using wx.CallAfter in AddText method:

```
def AddText(self, text):
    wx.CallAfter(self.OutText.AppendText, text)
```

but it's useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call wxPython methods directly from a thread. So the line

```
self.cb(text)
```

won't work. But if you put that into a threadsafe method, such as wx.CallAfter, then it should work. See the following links:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

I also wrote a tutorial on redirecting stuff from stdout to a text control here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/05/python-running-ping-traceroute-and-more/